# Mount SFB ReadyNAS share in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, permissions, mount, samba

I have a ReadyNAS RN104 with a single SMB share on it with Anonymous access allowed.

From my Mac I can see the share in Finder and mount it by clicking the ReadyNAS and then double clicking the share. No authentication is needed as I have anonymous access and can read and write to the share.

From Windows, I can browse the share with `\\ReadyNAS\share` and again I have full read/write access to this share.

I'm now trying to become more familiar with Ubuntu so I built a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server out of an old desktop. I created a mount point `/media/ReadyNAS/share` and check my regular user could write to the location with `touch /media/ReadyNAS/share/test`. All good.

Then, I mounted the ReadyNAS share into the mount point with `sudo mount -t cifs \\ReadyNAS\share /media/ReadyNAS/share` but upon testing if I can write to that share, I get permission denied.

I have also tried mounting with the username and password of a user account on the ReadyNAS like so: `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=myuser,pass=mypass \\ReadyNAS\share /media/ReadyNAS/share`but I get the same result.

I have also tried NFS, but I am not familiar with that so I that may be a step to far initially.

What am I not doing correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what happens when you take possession of the mounted mount point:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //ReadyNAS/share /media/ReadyNAS/share -o guest,uid=1000,nounix
```

**uid=1000** should be your user id number. To verify run this command and change it if necessary:

```
id
```

Comment: So that sorted my issue!